# How to automatically replace mimetype when unzipping?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zip, epub

I'm using the following command to unzip epub files recursively inside a folder:

```
find -iname \*.epub -exec unzip {} \;
```

It works. But the terminal asks me this each time a file is being extracted:

> replace mimetype? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:

Is there a flag that I can add to the command so it automatically selects `[A]ll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite existing files without prompting, use `unzip`’s `-o` option:

```
find -iname \*.epub -exec unzip -o {} \;
```

If you only want to avoid being prompted, a safer option would be `-n` — it skips files which already exist, instead of overwriting them, again without prompting.